# Rendering BSP with VBO or shader? OpenGL

Tags: opengl, render, vbo

Is it possible to render BSP files from games from within shaders? Is it possible to have a VBO in a shader or does it need to be rendered client side?

Also for VBOs does it make sense to create an array of visible faces from your current PVS and frustum and then render then in batches by matching textures?

Comment: Pedantic note: there's no such thing as a "VBO" in OpenGL. There are only buffer objects, which can be used to store vertex data. Or uniform blocks. Or a variety of other things.

Answer (score 2):

A shader cannot *directly* provoke rendering. It cannot cause OpenGL to render some data. Shaders are part of the rendering pipeline, and that pipeline goes one way; it isn't allowed to loop.

In GL 4.x-based hardware, a shader could theoretically write data in a specific format that will be read via one of the "Indirect" rendering functions. But the client code, the CPU, still must actually issue the drawing command.

It's probably better to do visibility stuff in a compute language like OpenCL. OpenGL shaders are capable of it, but they're not well designed to make doing that intuitive. OpenCL is a general compute system, and it is designed to do that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to render BSP files from games from within shaders?

With a lot of PITA it may be possible on OpenGL-4 class systems. But, why? As soon as you start thinking in that direction you're doing something fundamentally wrong. And I'd bet, that such a pure-shader based BSP renderer on a current GPU was actually outperformed by a 10 year old GeForce2 and well written client side code.

Remember folks: *Doing things in the shader* **=/=** *High performance*

OpenGL never has been, and never will be a self-contained rendering engine. It's always been meant as the backend rasterizer API for a customly written renderer.